# Elequent inner join to only one line from right table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to join multiple tables on my first, all of the tables have the same amount of rows and joins perfectly. But joining the last table that has many lines exactly the same except the dates added so it duplicates my data to the amount of months per user. Is it possible to join just on one of the lines. it does not matter which one.

```
$rekeninge = DB::connection('odbc')
->table($this->mgk . '.D000M00L')
->leftJoin($this->div . '.D050M00P', $this->div . '.D050M00P.RKNR', '=', $this->mgk . '.D000M00L.RKNR')
->leftJoin($this->mgk . '.VFDIND00P', $this->mgk . '.VFDIND00P.F06', '=', $this->mgk . '.D000M00L.RKNR')
->leftJoin($this->mgk . '.VINDEXP', $this->mgk . '.VINDEXP.VNAAM', '=', $this->mgk . '.VFDIND00P.VFDVELDID')
->where([
    'F02' => 'A',
    'F165' => 'D'
])
->get();
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: "it does not matter which one" It *should* matter! The fact that is doesn't is sometimes symptomatic of poor design!!

Comment: It does not matter because monthly that table is updated with a debtors monthly change. I do not care for the change I only seek the debtors Name and surname which is recorded on every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group` the results `by` one of the columns:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

so your query would end up being something like this:

```
$rekeninge = DB::connection('odbc')
->table($this->mgk . '.D000M00L')
->leftJoin($this->div . '.D050M00P', $this->div . '.D050M00P.RKNR', '=', $this->mgk . '.D000M00L.RKNR')
->leftJoin($this->mgk . '.VFDIND00P', $this->mgk . '.VFDIND00P.F06', '=', $this->mgk . '.D000M00L.RKNR')
->leftJoin($this->mgk . '.VINDEXP', $this->mgk . '.VINDEXP.VNAAM', '=', $this->mgk . '.VFDIND00P.VFDVELDID')
->where([
    'F02' => 'A',
    'F165' => 'D'
])
->groupBy('month')
->get();
```

Comment: Performance benefits aside, in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is rarely a good idea.